# DateTime comparison using path range index

Tags: marklogic-10

I don't know whether it is doable or not but still I want to ask this question,

Lets say there are two xml documents in database as below,

```
URI - /item/A
<test>
    <itemName>A</itemName>
    <dateTime>2021-08-18T17:16:25</dateTime>
</employee>


URI - /item/B
<test>
    <itemName>B</itemName>
    <dateTime>2021-08-18T17:16:25.123</dateTime>
</employee>
```

I am getting value for xpath `/test/dateTime` like `2021-08-18T17:16:25`(without milliseconds) from UI and based on this value I want to perform search to get all the documents where value of `/test/dateTime` equal to `2021-08-18T17:16:25` and I am expecting both the document(by ignoring milliseconds from doc `/item/B`) as result.

Path range index is also there for xpath `/test/dateTime`.

**Update**

I tried below query but it is returning only one document `/item/A` because it matches exact value on this document, but my requirement is to get both the document by ignoring milliseconds from second value, `2021-08-18T17:16:25.123`

```
cts:search(doc(), cts:and-query((cts:path-range-query("/test/dateTime", "=", "2021-08-18T17:16:25"))), ("unfiltered"))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What have you tried? What went wrong? Share your code.

Comment: @gshpychka Thanks for reply, what is not clear, what is the confusion, I updated my question, Please take a look.

Comment: Trye a `cts:field-value-query` with a wildcard.